# Updating large record sets into a normalized Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, normalization

I'm using Access 2007 to build a normalized database to replace one that uses a couple of flat many-field tables.  My problem is that I often get Excel sheets with lots of updates that I import as tables and then join against an existing table to do updates.  But that's going to be more difficult now that I'm normalizing.  Here's an example of the VBA code for updating a value:

```
function updateBoxCategory(boxID As String, newCategory As String) as long

Dim boxKey As Long
Dim catKey As Long
Dim db As Database
Dim ustr As String

Set db = CurrentDb


boxKey = getKey(db, "boxes", "boxID", boxID)

'exit if box not found'
If boxKey = 0 Then
 Exit Sub
End If

catKey = getKey(db, "categories", "category", newCategory)

'exit if category not found'
If catKey = 0 Then
 Exit Sub
End If

ustr = "update boxes set catKey=" & catKey & " where ID=" & boxKey
db.Execute ustr, dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

getKey("dbObject","table","field","value") returns a unique value's primary key.

I'm concerned that if, e.g., I have to update 100,000 records, I'll have to loop this procedure's queries through every record, which means I'll be running 100,000 select queries against a table with 100,000 records--and this makes me worried about performance issues, even though everything's indexed.

Basically, my question is this: is this code the appropriate way to handle updates to normalized data?

Comment: Why do you first lookup "boxKey" from "boxes" ?  Seems like you could just use "boxID" directly in your update on the boxes table.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I'm trying to find out whether "boxID" is found in the table; getKey returns 0 if the value is not found.  I want to be able to notify the user if there was an attempt to update a record that doesn't exist.

Comment: you could use the RecordsAffected property following the Execute to see whether any records were updated: this would save you work if most of your updates are successful.  As for your main question, I'm not sure I understand the issue: is it just performance you're worried about ?

Comment: @TimWilliams- thanks for the tip about RecordsAffected, however, I'd also like to report back which updates failed so the user can check those for validation issues. re: main question, it seems like normalizing makes the update/insert/delete process more complicated, instead of writing one SQL statement I have to write a bunch of VBA code every time I want to develop a new query.  Also more resource-intensive: don't I want to just do one update from a joined table as opposed to a separate select/update for every joined record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL we shun such procedural code in favour of set-based solutions. The ides is that you tell the optimizer in a single SQL statement what you want to achieve and it (rather than you) decides how best to do it.

I assume you have a staging table (could be in Excel, could be a linked table) with columns for the real keys, `boxID` and `newCategory`. However, you cannot use these values in your `Boxes` table because there is some indirection in the schema design: you need to find the 'surrogate' key values using a look up tables (I urge you to consider fixing this "feature" in your design so you can just use the real key values :)

Here's how it can be done with Standard SQL:2003 (e.g. works on SQL Server 2008):

```
MERGE INTO Boxes
   USING (
          SELECT B1.ID AS boxKey, C1.ID AS catKey
            FROM YourStagingTable AS S1
                 INNER JOIN Boxes AS B1
                    ON B1.boxID = S1.boxID
                 INNER JOIN Categories AS C1
                    ON C1.category = S1.NewCategory
         ) AS source (
                      boxKey, catKey
                     )
      ON Boxes.ID = source.boxKey
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET catKey = source.catKey;
```

Here is the equivalent in SQL-92 Standard, which required the use of scalar subqueries:

```
UPDATE Boxes
   SET catKey = 
                (
                 SELECT C1.ID AS catKey
                   FROM YourStagingTable AS S1
                         INNER JOIN Boxes AS B1
                            ON B1.boxID = S1.boxID
                         INNER JOIN Categories AS C1
                            ON C1.category = S1.NewCategory
                  WHERE Boxes.ID = B1.ID
                ) 
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM YourStagingTable AS S1
                       INNER JOIN Boxes AS B1
                          ON B1.boxID = S1.boxID
                WHERE Boxes.ID = B1.ID
              );
```

Sadly, Access (Jet, ACE, whatever) does not support any of the modern SQL Standards even at entry level (if something from 1992 can indeed be considered 'modern' :) Rather, Access insists you use its propriety `UPDATE..JOIN` syntax, with which I've never been really familiar. Hopefully the above will point you in the right direction for Access (or erhaps someone can edit this answer to add the equivalent Access dialect...?)

Comment: @onedaywhen- I understand that it's important not to use the actual Category name as a key because the primary key is supposed to be separate from the content data--if I had to change the spelling of that Category then I'd have to change it for every box with that value, as opposed to changing it once in the lookup table.

Comment: @sigil:"I understand that it's important not to use the actual Category name" ... your "understanding" may be incorrect: using a surrogate key is merely one school of thought... "the primary key is supposed to be separate from the content data" -- no, that's not correct, even if you do advocate using surrogate keys. Which key gets to be designated "primary" is arbitrary. Sure, the DBMS may attach special meaning to primary keys (e.g. Access makes the PK name bold in the 'Relationships' picture thing) but the same is not the case for the data model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here, but if you're trying to match up a row in a table with a row in a spreadsheet and copy values that differ from the spreadsheet to the table, you need to rotate your approach 90 degrees.

That is, instead of running a SQL UPDATE for each ROW, run one for each COLUMN.

Here's code that does this. It assumes that the two tables being compared have a shared primary key and that they have the same field names (though you can write a query that aliases the fields in one to match the names in the other):

```
  Public Function UpdateTableData(ByVal strSourceTable As String, _
       ByVal strTargetTable As String, ByVal strJoinField As String, _
       ByRef db As DAO.Database, Optional ByVal strExcludeFieldsList As String, _
       Optional ByVal strUpdatedBy As String = "Auto Update", _
       Optional strAdditionalCriteria As String) As Boolean
    Dim strUpdate As String
    Dim rsFields As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strFieldName As String
    Dim strNZValue As String
    Dim strSet As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim STR_QUOTE = """"

    strUpdate = "UPDATE " & strTargetTable & " INNER JOIN " & strSourceTable _
       & " ON " & strTargetTable & "." & strJoinField & " = " _
       & strSourceTable & "." & strJoinField
    ' if the fields don't have the same names in both tables,
    '   create a query that aliases the fields to have the names of the
    '   target table
    ' if the source table is in a different database and you don't
    '   want to create a linked table, create a query and specify
    '   the external database as the source of the table
    ' alternatively, for strTargetTable, supply a SQL string with
    '   the external connect string
    Set rsFields = db.OpenRecordset(strSourceTable)
    For Each fld In rsFields.Fields
      strFieldName = fld.Name
      If strFieldName <> strJoinField Or (InStr(", " & strExcludeFieldsList _
           & ",", strFieldName & ",") <> 0) Then
         Select Case fld.Type
           Case dbText, dbMemo
             strNZValue = "''"
           Case Else
             strNZValue = "0"
         End Select
         strSet = " SET " & strTargetTable & "." & strFieldName _
           & " = varZLSToNull(" & strSourceTable & "." & strFieldName & ")"
         strSet = strSet & ", " & strTargetTable & ".Updated = #" & Date & "#"
         strSet = strSet & ", " & strTargetTable & ".UpdatedBy = " _
           & STR_QUOTE & strUpdatedBy & STR_QUOTE
         strWhere = " WHERE Nz(" & strTargetTable & "." & strFieldName _
           & ", " & strNZValue & ") <> Nz(" & strSourceTable & "." _
           & strFieldName & ", " & strNZValue & ")"
         If db.TableDefs(strTargetTable).Fields(fld.Name).Required Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & strSourceTable & "." _
              & strFieldName & " Is Not Null"
         End If
         If Len(strAdditionalCriteria) > 0 Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & strAdditionalCriteria
         End If
         Debug.Print strUpdate & strSet & strWhere
         Debug.Print SQLRun(strUpdate & strSet & strWhere, dbLocal) & " " _
           & strFieldName & " updated."
      End If
    Next fld
    Debug.Print dbLocal.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " _
      & strTargetTable & " WHERE Updated=#" & Date _
      & "# AND UpdatedBy=" & STR_QUOTE & strUpdatedBy & STR_QUOTE)(0) _
      & " total records updated in " & strTargetTable
    rsFields.Close
    Set rsFields = Nothing
    UpdateTableData = True
  End Function
```

I've been using variations on that code for well over a decade, and it's much faster and more efficient than doing it row-by-row.

Do note that there are some assumptions hardwired into it (like the fact that each table has Updated and UpdatedBy fields). But it should get you started.